# Python blobs.BlobResult module import error

Tags: python, opencv, cvblobslib

After install blobs package on Debian. am getting the error like

```
libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 8, in <module>
    from blobs.BlobResult import CBlobResult
ImportError: No module named blobs.BlobResult
```

I trying to run [that code](http://andorian.blogspot.com/2013/02/automatic-number-plate-detection.html).
OpenCv and cvBlob already installed.
Can anyone help me to run that code?

Comment: unfortunately horribly outdated. opencv3 won't support anything like cv anymore, only cv2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you forget to install the python wrapper for cvBlob:

https://github.com/oostendo/cvblob-python